# PHP - YouTube Live API - Get video ID

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, youtube, feed

What I want to do is get a list of all the live videos currently playing on YouTube and either embed them or if not possible at least link to the YouTube they're available at.

The code for retrieving the feed using the Zend framework is pretty straightforward.

```
    $videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/charts/live/events/live_now');
    foreach ($videoFeed as $videoEntry) {
        printVideoEntry($videoEntry);
    }
```

And printVideoEntry() just displays a bunch of data about that video. It works for channel or playlist feeds. When it's used for live streams, a lot of data isn't present. It's just the title, description, and author. What I want is the video id of the video.

By requesting the feed's url, I get an xml of the feed. Below is one example video entry.

```
    <entry gd:etag='W/&quot;CUYEQ347eCp7I2A9WhJUFks.&quot;'>
<id>tag:youtube.com,2008:live:event:IKv8FeyLmiIl-8iUVVahpRaYMLRCD0xt</id>
<published>2012-09-14T21:14:31.000Z</published>
<updated>2012-09-14T22:51:42.000Z</updated>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#liveEvent'/>
<title>TGIFF Live Stream with Realm (League of Legends)</title>
<summary>Realm's Livestream: Thank God it's Freakin Friday! This week we're getting into some League of Legends action and teaching our ambitious Hundar how to play! This live show will air every Friday from 4-6pm PST on http://www.machinimalive.com 
Subscribe to the Machinima Live newsletter here! http://eepurl.com/o1-kP</summary>

<content type='application/atom+xml' src='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MachinimaRealm/live/videos/YbeDQJ_FSVA?v=2'/>
<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/VEbcFWM43PS-d5vaSKUMng/live/events/IKv8FeyLmiIl-8iUVVahpRaYMLRCD0xt?v=2'/>
<author><name>MachinimaRealm</name><uri>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MachinimaRealm</uri><yt:userId>VEbcFWM43PS-d5vaSKUMng</yt:userId></author>

<media:group><media:description type='plain'>Realm's Livestream: Thank God it's Freakin Friday! This week we're getting into some League of Legends action and teaching our ambitious Hundar how to play! This live show will air every Friday from 4-6pm PST on http://www.machinimalive.com 
Subscribe to the Machinima Live newsletter here! http://eepurl.com/o1-kP</media:description><media:title type='plain'>TGIFF Live Stream with Realm (League of Legends)</media:title></media:group><yt:status>active</yt:status><yt:when end='2012-09-15T01:00:00.000Z' start='2012-09-14T22:51:42.000Z'/></entry>
```

The 'content' item contains the video id as 'src', but I don't know how to access it.

```
echo $videoEntry->content->src
```

returns null.

Would someone be able to help me out with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you `var_dump` the entire object? It doesn't seem like a PHP problem, but a Zend Framework specific problem.
(also, putting a `zend-framework` tag should lend better results for your question)

Comment: Thanks, although var_dumping the object produces a lot of data from Zend and it becomes hard to navigate.

-Beginning of output-
object(Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry)#30 (38) { ["_entryClassName:protected"]=> string(29) "Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry" ["_noEmbed:protected"]=> NULL ["_statistics:protected"]=> NULL ["_racy:protected"]=> NULL ["_private:protected"]=> NULL ["_rating:protected"]=> NULL ["_comments:protected"]=> NULL ["_feedLink:protected"]=> array(0) { } ["_where:protected"]=> NULL ["_recorded:protected"]=> NULL ["_location:protected"]=> NULL

The data I want is nested in there.